Embedding text in a terra raster?
Is there a simple way of embedding a given text in a terra raster, at a given position? Thanks,
Jean-Luc

I do not understand the question. What does "embedding" mean in this context? Can you please elaborate?

Sorry about my English, which isn't very good. I was looking for a way to add some text to the plot of a terra raster, providing coordinates to locate this text at a chosen position. How to write "Hello world" at x=0.2 and x=45.7, for example?

You can use the base function text. For example,
library(terra)
r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
plot(r)
text(6.2, 50, "Hello World", pos=4)

